# In the home tab of twitter app in iOS, is the developer using scroll view or table view as the view class?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

If they use table view, how can I use the continuous line separator instead of the default line separator in the table view?

Comment: Instead of posting your question to reference an app that could change at any time and isn't used by everyone, post a question that stands on its own. Describe exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

They (almost certainly) use UITableView and they set a separator in UITableViewCell property with custom insets set to zero:

[image: img taken from storyboard of a UITableViewCell with a continuous separator]